# Hudson - Can't Poll Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, hudson

I have Hudson 2.1.2 (not Jenkins) and I've set my projects up to poll my Mercurial repository hourly to check for changes.  I generated a public key for my hudson user and added it to the authorized keys on my Mercurial server.  When doing the hourly poll, sometimes some projects can't poll Mercurial.  Here's an example of what I see in the Mercurial Polling Log:

```
Started on Apr 30, 2012 2:00:30 PM
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/hg incoming --style /opt/home/hudson/jobs/MyProject/workspace/tmp7506244240405638202style --no-merges --rev default --newest-first
remote: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
Done. Took 5.3 sec
No changes
```

However, if I click on "Build Now", it sucessfully polls, picks up changes and builds.

```
Started by user sdoca
Cleaning the workspace because project is configured to clean the workspace before each build.
$ /usr/bin/hg clone --rev default ssh://hudson@my.mercurial.server:22//opt/hg/current/MyProject /opt/home/hudson/jobs/MyProject/workspace
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 31 changesets with 40 changes to 11 files
updating working directory
5 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/hg log --rev . --template {node}
[INFO] Using bundled Maven 3 installation
[INFO] Checking Maven 3 installation environment
...
<snip>
```

Any ideas why I get an error on the auto poll?

Comment: it looks like you have incorrect path in hgrc file. As a brute-force solution you can wipe the workspace.

Comment: No, the path in the hgrc file is correct.  If it wasn't correct the manual "Build Now" wouldn't work either.

Comment: same problem with Hudson 3.1.0 - polling error ssh_exchange_identification, but build works, also typing polling command on command line works